# How Can I Bypass the X-Frame-Options

Tags: angular, typescript, x-frame-options

Im trying when click link it will show a website in iframe but I got problem with x-frame-option. Then, I use `x-frame-bypass`. It working when I using in **HTML** like bellow.

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe is="x-frame-bypass" src="https://news.ycombinator.com/" name="myIframe"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

But, when I trying click link and open in iframe it not working. I'm using angular. Example code like bellow.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
   Test Open URL in Iframe
  </h1>
  <a class="link-call" (click)="onTest('https://news.ycombinator.com/')" style="background:red;padding: 14px 25px;color:white;cursor:pointer">test</a>
  </div>


<iframe is="x-frame-bypass" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
name = 'Set iframe source';
  url: string;
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  onTest(url){
    this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
```

This [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-src-6ibdt6) for your reference

Comment: did you find the solution ,if yes can you share